# selenium js click element until text is not equal

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In nodejs i want to click element until text in some other element is not equal to '100'

I try to write code like this:

```
while (this.getLinkText() != '100') { 
    this.clickOnButton();
}
```

I don't know how to do this with js selenium-webdriver because when i try to get text of element in this way

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(this.path)).getText();
```

it returns 'promise' not a string, so i don't know how to use it in while loop

Comment: what is this.path ?

Comment: path to element eg. "/html/body/.article/button"

Comment: can u post the html source?

Comment: My path is correct because if i do something like this

    `driver.findElement(By.xpath(this.path)).getText().then(function (text) {
        console.log(text);
    });`
shows the text which I expect

Answer (score 0):

While loop is a road to nowhere, try to use a recursive function with callback.
I had a similar problem, it was necessary to select the year in calendar (click 'next' until I have got a correct year)

```js
var yearToFind = '2016';

function chooseYear(callback) {
    // get current year from calendar
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('.//*[@class="ui-datepicker-year"]'))
    .getText()
    .then(function(currentYear) {
        if (currentYear != yearToFind) {
            // click "next year" button and call chooseYear function again
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('.//a[@class="ui-datepicker-next-year"]'))
            .then(function(subelement) {
                subelement.click().then(function() {
                    chooseYear(callback)
                });
            })
        } else {
            // do your actions if the year is correct
            callback();
        }
    });
}

chooseYear(function() {
    console.log('I have got the correct year finally!');
});
```